# Import CSV table in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, csv, import

I want import in PostgreSQL csv table with next structure:

```
1,qw,sdf,ty
2,efw,sd,hj,gh,hj
3,sfd,sd,gf,gh,h
4,fg,sd,dff
```

I use sql query:

```
CREATE TABLE test("nom" integer, "f1" text, "f2" text, "f3" text, "f4" text, "f5" text);

COPY bptable("nom", "f1", "f2", "f3", "f4", "f5")
FROM 'D:\data.csv'
WITH DELIMITER ',' CSV;
```

But receive exception: ERROR: extra data after last expected column SQL state: 22P04, row 2.
Hope someone can help. Advance thanks.

Comment: That's a malformed CSV file. You are missing the trailing commas after the last column in rows 1 and 4 (both are missing two column values).

Answer (score 1):

I've never imported data using CSV before, but you have 4 'columns' in your CSV file (line 1 and 4) and 5 columns in your SQL table.

EDIT: You will need to specifiy which column is missing data as so:

```
1,bla1,bla2,,bla3
```

Note the double coma between bla2 and bla3